# Prove that if u + w = v + w then u = v (without additive inverse)

Tags: linear-algebra

For vectors u, w, and v in a vector space V, I am trying to prove:

If $u + w = v + w$ then $u = v$

**without** using the additive inverse and only using the 8 axioms which define a vector space. I am coming up short. I don't see how to do this without assuming that if $u + w = v + w$ then I can just add something to both sides as in $(u+w) + w' = (v+w) + w'$.

Thank you.

Comment: What are $u$, $v$, and $w$?

Comment: What are the other axioms?

Comment: u, v, and w are vectors in a vector space V. By "other axioms" I meant the typical 8 axioms to which a set must abide to to be considered a vector space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the only approach for a vector space $V$ that avoids additive inverses *in $V$* is to use $w'=(-1)w$, which would leverage additive inverses in *the field* and not in the abelian group. Presumably your axioms (whatever they are) include that $0w=0$, $1w=w$ and that scalars distribute, allowing you to continue $$u+0=u+(1-1)w=u+w+(-1)w=v+w+(-1)w=v+(1-1)w=v+0$$.

If this sorcery of scalars is not available to you, and you are only allowed to talk about a binary operation, then it is not always possible. A set with a binary operation $\cdot$ (no inverses assumed) does not have this "cancellation property."

For example, in a boolean ring, the multiplication operation satisfies $x\cdot x =x$ for all $x$, and so you would have, in particular, the equation $x\cdot x = x\cdot 1$, but of course you can choose and example where $x\neq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You will just have to add a $w'$ indeed, namely, try $w':=(-1)\cdot w$ and use
$$(\alpha+\beta)w=\alpha w+\beta w$$
for certain $\alpha,\beta$ scalars.

Answer (score 0):

The additive cancellation law you're trying to prove is *equivalent* to the additive inverse axiom, which strongly suggests you *can't* prove it without assuming that axiom.

That is, let's take the standard eight axioms from the Wikipedia page for vector spaces, slightly modified by writing $\Omega$ for the "zero" vector and $\overline v$ for the additive inverse:

> Associativity of addition:    $u + (v + w) = (u + v) + w$
>
> Commutativity of addition:    $u + v = v + u$
>
> Identity element of addition: There exists an element $\Omega \in V$
>   such that $v + \Omega = v$ for all $v \in V$.
>
> Inverse elements of addition: For every $v \in V$, there exists an
>   element $\overline v \in V$ such that $v + \overline v = \Omega$.
>
> Compatibility of scalar multiplication with field
>   multiplication:   $a(bv) = (ab)v$
>
> Identity element of scalar multiplication:    $1v = v$, where $1$ denotes
>   the multiplicative identity in $F$.
>
> Distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to vector
>   addition:     $a(u + v) = au + av$
>
> Distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to field
>   addition: $(a + b)v = av + bv$

Note that

$$0\cdot v=(1-1)\cdot v=1\cdot v+(-1)\cdot v=v+(-1)\cdot v$$

just from the axioms for scalar multiplication.  Now *if* we knew (or had as an axiom) that $0\cdot v=\Omega$ for all $v\in V$, then we wouldn't need the additive inverse axiom at all: we'd be able to conclude that $(-1)\cdot v$ is the $\overline v$ whose existence that axiom asserts.  But we *don't* know that $0\cdot v=\Omega$.

However, we do know that

$$\Omega+w = w = 1\cdot w=(0+1)\cdot w=0\cdot w+1\cdot w=0\cdot w+ w$$

So suppose we substitute the OP's cancellation law for the additive inverse axiom.  Then we can cancel the $w$ from the two ends of the above, concluding

$$\Omega=0\cdot w$$

for any $w\in V$.

In summary, if you fix the other seven axioms, then the additive inverse axiom, the "multiplication by $0$" law, and the OP's cancellation law are all equivalent.  So if you believe (or can prove) that the standard eight axioms are independent, then there's no way to prove the cancellation law from the other seven (standard) axioms.