# The question of linear space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Let $V$ be a vector space and $v \in V$ . Prove that

\begin{align*}
-v = (-1) \cdot v
\end{align*}

by only using the vector spaces axioms.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof that $-v = (-1)*v$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952737/proof-that-v-1v)

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\Bbb{K}$ and $v \in V$. We first prove that $0_{\Bbb{K}} \cdot v = 0_V$. We have that

\begin{align*}
0_{\mathbb{K}} \cdot v & = (0_{\Bbb{K}} + 0_{\Bbb{K}}) \cdot v & (0_{\Bbb{K}} \in \Bbb{K} \text{ identity for $+_{\Bbb{K}}$}) \\
& = 0_{\Bbb{K}} \cdot v + 0_{\Bbb{K}} \cdot v & (\text{distributive law})
\end{align*}

Next, note that you can add $- 0_{\Bbb{K}} \cdot v$ to each side of the above equality (*Why?*). From this you will get that $0_{\Bbb{K}} \cdot v = 0_V$. Then we conclude that

\begin{align*}
v + (-1)\cdot v & = 1_{\Bbb{K}} \cdot v + (-1) \cdot v & (1_{\Bbb{K}} \in \Bbb{K} \text{ identity for } \cdot) \\
& = (1_{\Bbb{K}} + (-1)) \cdot v & (\text{distributive law}) \\
& = 0_{\Bbb{K}} \cdot v & (\text{existence of multiplicative inverse}) \\
& = 0_V
\end{align*}

Hence, we have that $(-1) \cdot v \in V$ is a symmetric of $v$. I will assume that you already have proved that the symmetric element of $v$ is unique (if not, you can ask), so we conclude that $-v=(-1)\cdot v$. $\square$

Any doubt on this, please let me know.